Is there a way to capture output from sp_whoisactive on another server?
I am currently using sp_whoIsAcive to capture performance data and am storing this on the server for later analysis. But I also have several Azure hosted servers and it's not possible to be able to run the sp via a scheduled task.
Is there a way I can fire off then sp on another server to gather the info from an azure db and collect the output onto the server where the sp was fired from?
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

What happens if you use a linked server then EXEC LinkedServer.master.dbo.sp_whoisactive

That was my initial thought but the azure db will not accept this
